# How to extract the json data without square brackets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I suspect I am facing an issue because my json data is within square brackets ([]).
I am processing pubsub data which is in below format.

```
[{"ltime":"2022-04-12T11:33:00.970Z","cnt":199,"fname":"MYFILENAME","data":[{"NAME":"N1","ID":11.4,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"},{"NAME":"M1","ID":25.0,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"}]
```

I am successfully processing/extracting all the fields except 'data'. I need to create a json file using the 'data' in a cloud storage.

when I use `msg['data']` I am getting below,

```
[{"NAME":"N1","ID":11.4,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"},{"NAME":"M1","ID":25.0,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"}]
```

Sample code:

```
pubsub_msg = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
pubsub_data = json.loads(pubsub_msg)

json_file = pubsub_data['fname'] + '.json'
json_content = pubsub_data['data']
try:
    << call function >>
except Exception as e:
    << Error >>
```

below is the error I am getting it.

```
2022-04-12T17:35:01.761Zmyapp-pipelineeopcm2kjno5h Error in uploading json document to gcs: [{"NAME":"N1","ID":11.4,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"},{"NAME":"M1","ID":25.0,"DATE":"2005-10-14 00:00:00"}] could not be converted to bytes
```

I am not sure the issue is because of square brackets [].
Correct me if I am wrong and please help to get the exact json data for creating a file.

Comment: Please post a valid `list`/json and your code.

Comment: In the second example, you NEED the square brackets.  You have a collection of two objects.  Collections in JSON are surrounded by square brackets.  Your first example is not correct syntax; that first open bracket doesn't have a closing one.  PLEASE REMEMBER that your data doesn't actually include any square brackets.  That's just a list of things, and in Python, we PRINT lists by using square brackets.

Comment: `pubsub_data` is not JSON.  It is a native Python data structure.  It can be CONVERTED to JSON, but as it sits it is not.  `json_content` is a list of dictionaries.  It also is not JSON, although it can be converted to JSON.  What, exactly, is the error you get?

Comment: I am getting the error - could not be converted to bytes.

Comment: Can you post the proper error message?

Comment: So, the error is not part of this code at all.  The error happens when you try to pass `json_content` to something else, which you decided not to show us.  Despite not seeing the code, issue is that you are passing a data structure to something that is expecting JSON.  So, convert it:  `json.dumps(json_content)`.  You might change that variable name, since it is not really JSON.